# cannot connect to the docker daemon error, not a default path

Tags: docker, installation

i installed docker engine and docker desktop
and i run the command docker ps.

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/gunbos/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I known /var/lib/docker as the default folder.
I don't know why the default path is changed.

I've tried all the google solutions, but it doesn't work.

I think it is solved by change path where daemon runs, but can't find how to change the path...

If someone know the how to change the path where docker find docker running, let me know that way, please...

Comment: try running the docker ps command with sudo. If it's not giving you any error then you are might be missing the 'docker' group permission for current (general) user. Also check your docker service is running.

Comment: @ras thank you soooo much.... it works with sudo keyword